# Link that sets a parameter in the URL doesn't work as expected when I try $_GET

Tags: php, url, cookies, gettext, page-refresh

I have this PHP code that sets a cookie when the `?setLang` parameter is in the URL

```
if (isSet($_GET["setLang"])) {
    setcookie("lang",$_GET["setLang"]);
}

if (!isSet($_COOKIE["lang"])) {
    //negociate language and set locale
}else{
    //set locale to cookie
}

//translate with gettex
```

When I go to website.com/?setLand=en it works exactly as expected.

The problem is when I link to the URL in this form from website.com:

```
<a href="?setLang=en">en</a>
```

When I click it, through the link (and not go directly) the gettext translation doesn't work, but otherwise, it works as expected.

My first though was that I had to force some kind of refresh, so I did:

```
<a href="?setLang=en" onClick="window.location.reload( true );">en</a>
```

But it doesn't work.

I inspected the code and the cookie is in fact set when you click the link so it confuses me even further.

---

---

The full code just in case is the following:

```
<?php
if (isSet($_GET["setLang"])) {
    setcookie("lang",$_GET["setLang"]);
}
if (!isSet($_COOKIE["lang"])) {
    $langs = array(
        'en-US',// default
        'fr',
        'fr-FR',
        'de',
        'de-DE',
        'de-AT',
        'de-CH',
    );
    $locale = substr(http_negotiate_language($langs), 0, 2);
}else{
    $locale = $_COOKIE["lang"];
}

//if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
if($locale == "en") 
    $locale = "en_US.utf8";
if($locale == "de") 
    $locale = "de_DE.utf8";
if($locale == "fr") 
    $locale = "fr_FR.utf8";

putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

// Specify location of translation tables
bindtextdomain("translation", "locale");

// Choose domain
textdomain("translation");

// Translation is looking for in ./locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo now

// Print a test message
//echo _("title");
?>
```

and the link:

```
...
<a href="?setLang=en" onClick="window.location.reload( true );">en</a>
...
```

Comment: Probably your cookie works for website.com but not for localhost or whatever IP is assigned when you use the link without the FQDN. So try also `// Another way to debug/test is to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);`

Comment: Hm, interesting, I'll try it on the server just in case. When I inspect with it says that the cookie is called lang is set, but when I print $_COOKIE it doesn't show...

Comment: @ndasusers So I tried it in the server with no luck, when I print $_COOKIE the results are the following: When I got to the main domain: `Array ( [force_locale] => en [hl] => en )` when I click the link: `Array ( [force_locale] => en [hl] => en )` (no change) and when I refresh or enter the link directly: `Array ( [lang] => de [force_locale] => en [hl] => en )`

Comment: Can you use session variables? I think they match your expectations better.

Comment: @Barmar I absolutely can, I have no experiece with them, but I'll take a look, what would be the main difference?

Comment: They automatically ensure that the value you set is retained, instead of you having to check and set cookies explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar hmm interesting. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setcookie()` adds a header to the output and does not alter the `$_COOKIE` superglobal.

```
if (isSet($_GET['setLang'])) {
    $locale = $_GET['setLang'];
    setcookie('lang', $locale);
} elseif (isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $locale = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
    $langs = array('en-US', 'fr', 'fr-FR', 'de', 'de-DE', 'de-AT', 'de-CH');
    $locale = substr(http_negotiate_language($langs), 0, 2);
}
```

will do what you want.

Comment: So what I did (that works by chance) would also be correct? insted of only set cookie I did: `$_COOKIE['lang'] =$_GET['setLang'];
    setcookie("lang",$_GET['setLang']);`??

Comment: Might work - but you should never write to a request variable. You want the value in `$locale`, so it is the correct solution to put it there.

Comment: You solution doesn't seem to be working... When I click the link it changes and translates the site but when I close the tab and reopen, the cookie is not set and so the language goes to the default again...

Comment: Thanks, that's almost there, but maybe I'm not getting something right, because it works when I close the tab but not when I close the browse and reopen... Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: That's expected behavior. The cookie is just a session cookie. Look into the [PHP manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for more information.

Comment: Ahh ok, so, I need another typo of cookie? I'll look into it

Comment: You just have to set a proper expiration period.

Comment: Indeed that solved that, sorry I couldn't accept it before, I was without my pc... thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

When you have a link you don't need to reload anything, 'cause the link will be default (if you don't say it to don't) lead to another page.

Are you sure are you pointing it to the correct file? Try some debug like sending the exact file you are proccessing it in the URL, like for example:

```
<a href="home.php?setLang=en">en</a>
```

For debugging propuses, you could use the PHP print_r that will help you understand what are you getting in $_GET.

Just do this in the start of your PHP code:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
//the rest of your code
?>
```

Comment: Ok I did what you said and this are the results: still not displaying text in the correct language, and empty array at the beginning and then whn I click the link: `Array ( [setLang] => de )` as expected.

Comment: So, when you click it shows the text in correct language right? Instead of doing setcookie("lang",$_GET["setLang"]); try doing $_COOKIE['lang'] = $_GET['setLang'];

Comment: Wait, it just worked once but not again, give me a second, I'm clearly doing something strange.

Comment: Read the documentation of `setcookie()`. It says that it sets the cookies that will be sent to the browser. `$_COOKIES` contains the cookies that were received from the browser, not the ones that are going to be sent.

Comment: @IvoPereira I now sort of solved it, when I used ` $_COOKIE['lang'] =$_GET['setLang'];` it translated the text but it didnt actually solve the problem. What I did was both: `$_COOKIE['lang'] =$_GET['setLang'];
    setcookie("lang",$_GET['setLang']);` and it seem to work, but I don't understand what's going on!

Comment: Hmm, with error_reporting totally ON (error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors", true); on PHP) try doing a print_r($_COOKIE); right before the $_COOKIE['lang']=$_GET['setLang'] and after. And do the same stuff for the setcookie function. Check where is it really storing the lang value.